# Unable to print the character 'à' with the printf function in C

Tags: c, printf, fopen, fgetc

I would like to understand why I can print the character 'à' with the functions fopen and fgetc when I read a .txt file but I can't assign it to a char variable and print it with the printf function.

When I read the file texte.txt, the output is:

(Here is a letter that we often use in French: à)

The letter 'à' is correctly read by the fgetc function and assigned to the char c variable

See the code below:

```
int main() {

FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("texte.txt", "r");
  if (fp==NULL) {
    printf("erreur fopen");
    return 1; 
    }
char c = fgetc(fp);
    while(c != EOF) {
      printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(fp);
      
    }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;

  }
```

But now if I try to assign the 'à' character to a char variable, I get an error!
See the code below:

```
int main() {

char myChar = 'à';
printf("myChar is: %c\n", myChar);

  return 0;
  }
```

ERROR:
./main.c:26:15: error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
char myChar = 'à';

My knowledge in C is very insufficient, and I can't find an answer anywhere

Comment: `char` is suited for 1 byte value, ASCII table characters for example. `à` doesn't fit in 1 byte, check for `mb_char`, it's made for multi byte characters, and you have functions to work with them (`mb_strlen`instead of `strlen`). EDIT: Oops, That's for php, check `wchar_t`

Comment: You're looking for the header file ```<wchar.h>```.

Comment: You're using an encoding like UTF-8 where the character in question takes up several bytes, so it can't be stored in a single char

Comment: ouzz, `int fgetc(fp)` returns 1 of 257 different values.  Saving in a `char` will sometimes lose information.  Save in an `int` to avoid bugs.

Comment: The easiest is to use a string to store a multi-byte literal, `char *myString = "à"; printf("myChar is: %s\n", myString);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print `à` you can use wide character (or wide string):

```
#include <wchar.h>   // wchar_t
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>  // setlocale LC_ALL
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t a = L'à';
    printf("%lc\n", a);
}
```

In short: Characters have encoding. Program "locale" chooses what encoding is used by the standard library functions. A wide character represents a locale-agnostic character, a character that is "able" to be converted to/from any locale. `setlocale` set's your program locale to the locale of your terminal. This is needed so that `printf` knows how to convert wide character `à` to the encoding of your terminal. `L` in front of a character or string makes it a wide. On Linux, wide characters are in UTF-32.

Handling encodings might be hard. I can point to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII , https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode .

You can encode a multibyte string straight in your source code and output. This will work only if *your compiler* generates code for the multibyte string *in the same encoding* as your terminal works with. If you change your terminal encoding, or tell your compiler to use a different encoding, it may fail. On Linux, UTF-8 is everywhere, compilers generate UTF-8 string and terminals understand UTF-8.

```
const char *str = "à";
printf("%s\n", str);
```